# Want to fix html images to stick to one another in relative position

Tags: html, css

how to stick the two depicted images with the above two images.
I am using relative position for my responsive webpage.I have tried putting padding-top and margin-top to 0px. Want some helpful answer.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2hlc.png

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.long {
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.short {
  background-color: blue;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="short"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
  <div class="long"></div>
</div>
```